# $\operatorname{SO}(n)$ is an (abstractly) maximal subgroup of $\operatorname{SL}(n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, geometry, lie-groups

Can somebody explain to me a proof that $\operatorname{SO}(n)$ is a maximal subgroup of $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ meaning, that if you add one element to $\operatorname{SO}(n)$, you generate the whole $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$?

I am particularly interested in an inductive proof, and the induction step therein.

Comment: I haven't the slightest idea of how to prove this. Still, I sense that Gaussian elimination might play a role. Indeed, Gaussian elimination can be used to decompose matrices in $GL(n)$ in the product of the so-called "elementary" matrices, and maybe this is useful for the present question? As I said, I don't know, but maybe [the LU factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) is a good starting point. Sorry for being so vague.

Comment: I wonder why people are voting to close. It's a pity it is not possible to vote against closing!

Comment: @DerekHolt I suspect because it is not clear where the question comes from. Is it an exercise in a book, or a possibly open problem the OP came up with?

Comment: I also voted for reopening, it's a good question, and even if an exercise it's not a standard easy one.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm afraid you changed the meaning of the question to a much easier one and voted to close on these grounds. But the question was very clearly written from the beginning. The question is not whether it's maximal among compact subgroups, but among proper subgroups.

Comment: @YCor I didn't change the meaning. I asked about the context and gave a link of an MO-question on [maximal subgroups of $SL_n(\Bbb R)$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239095/maximal-subgroups-of-mathrmsln-mathbbr). There was no answer from the OP.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm referring the comment you've just erased, which asked if the question was to explain why $SO(n)$ is maximal compact. The now linked MO question is also easier (maximal connected).

Comment: A bit more context from the OP would be useful, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$n=2$. A geometric proof: $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$ acts on the hyperbolic plane as the full orientation-preserving isometry group with stabilizer $\mathrm{SO}(2)$. We need to check this action is primitive. Indeed, let $R$ be an invariant equivalence relation, not reduced to equality. Since the action is transitive on pairs at given distance, there exists a subset $M$ of $\mathbf{R}_{\ge 0}$, not reduced to $\{0\}$, such that $R$ equals the set of pairs at distance in $M$. Choose $r>0$ in $M$. Since any two points $x,y$ in the hyperbolic plane can be joined by a discrete path $x=x_0,\dots,x_n=y$ with $d(x_i,x_{i+1})=r$, we deduce that $xRy$. Hence $R$ is the indiscrete equivalence relation.

Now consider $n\ge 3$. Let $H$ be a subgroup properly containing $\mathrm{SO}(n)$. Let $D$ be the set of diagonal determinant 1 matrices with positive entries. Let $D_H$ be the intersection $D\cap H$. It is enough to show that $D_H=D$ (indeed, by polar decomposition it is enough to check that every positive determinant 1 symmetric matrix belongs to $H$, and using ortho-diagonalization, it is enough to check the latter for diagonal matrices). Moreover, again by the same polar decomposition argument, the assumption $H\neq\mathrm{SO}(n)$ implies that $D_H$ is not reduced to $\{1\}$.

Note that $D_H$ is stable under permutation of coordinates. Hence it contains some diagonal matrix $(t_1,t_2,t_3,\dots)$ with $0<t_2<1<t_1$. Hence it also contains the diagonal matrix $(t_2,t_1,t_3,\dots,t_n)$. Hence it contains the diagonal matrix $(u,u^{-1},1,\dots,1)$ with $u=t_1/t_2>1$. By the case $n=2$ applied to the $2\times 2$ north-west block, it therefore contains all matrices $(v,v^{-1},1,\dots,1)$. Hence, it also contains all its conjugates by permutations of coordinates. Since any element $(u_1,\dots,u_n)$ of $D$ (so $\prod u_i=1$) is the product of the diagonal matrices $(1,\dots,v_i,v_i^{-1},1,\dots,1)$ for $i=1\dots n-1$ with $v_i=u_1\dots u_i$, we deduce $D_H=D$, which finishes the proof.

---

Finally the most subtle case is $n=2$. In this case one can try a more direct approch. Namely write $K=\mathrm{SO}(2)$. By assumption there is a non-trivial element $g$ in $D_H$. I'd try to show that the map $K^3\to\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{R})$, mapping $(x,y,z)$ to $xgyg^{-1}z$, has its differential of rank 3 somewhere. Indeed, if so, it implies that its image has non-empty interior in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$, and hence $H$ has non-empty interior in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$, so is an open subgroup, so equals $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did not realise the question had been opened up again, so I didn't look again until now. Can you explain, why we can conclude that the diagonal matrix $(u,u^{-1},1...,1)$ lies in $D_H$?

Comment: @Julius I removed dots which were a typo: it contains both $a=(t_1,t_2,t_3,\dots)$ and $b=(t_2,t_1,t_3,\dots)$, hence it contains $ab^{-1}=(t_1/t_2,t_2/t_1,1,1\dots,1)$.